# Displaying selection based attributes in a table?

Tags: tables, data

I have a table column, where data should be entered through a dropbox. Depending on selection an additional value should be asked.

What is the best way to display this value in the table?

[image]

Comment: What does "Depending on selection" mean? Should an additional row be added, or just another available value in the drop down?

Comment: Dropdown Value "Einheitspreis" requires an additional Value "Preis"

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave some space out for it:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMUtn9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(Balsamiq didn't want to catch the € sign for some reasons...)

This way the size of the grid doesn't change, and even without an additional label it's obvious what's the input is for (esp. if you add a currency sign at the end)